# Checkbox don't show checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I'm working with checkbox input. When I click on checbox, checkbox don't show checked but checkbox's value I still get. I use React JS

## Simple checkbox

```
import React from 'react';
import callApi from './../../utils/apiCaller'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


class ProductActionPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: '',
            productStatus: ''
        }
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        var target = e.target;
        var name = target.name;
        var value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    render() {
        var statusCheckbox = this.state.productStatus === 'true' ? true : false;
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>Trang thai: </label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" checked={statusCheckbox} name="productStatus" onChange={this.onChange} />
                                Con hang
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Luu lai</button>
                        <Link to="/product/list" className="btn btn-danger ml-5">Huy bo</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

How can I show checked checkbox?

Comment: I guess `this.state.productStatus === 'true'` would have to be true ... the only value set for `state.productStatus` in your code is `''`

Comment: you mean I have to set status.productStatus: false or true???

Comment: I mean for the checkbox to be checked, productStatus (with your code) has to be exactly the string `"true"` for this to occur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.state.productStatus` is a boolean value, so your condition will always give you the `false`, because you are comparing `Boolean === String`.

Just change

```
var statusCheckbox = this.state.productStatus === 'true' ? true : false;
```

to

```
var statusCheckbox = this.state.productStatus ? true : false;   //It doesn't make any sense
```

Or simply

```
var statusCheckbox = this.state.productStatus;
```

Or you can directly use `this.state.productStatus`,

```
<input 
   type="checkbox" 
   checked={this.state.productStatus} 
   name="productStatus" 
   onChange={this.onChange} 
/>
```

Comment: If I use this.state.productStatus, I will get a warning "Received the string `false` for the boolean attribute `checked`. The browser will interpret it as a truthy value. Did you mean checked={false}"

Comment: @HuyVuThe yes productStatus is a `string` here just turn it to boolean to make it work, `productStatus :true`

Comment: @HuyVuThe you can have initial state `productStatus: false`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I set status field's datatype in database is varchar so I must convert status data I have got in database into boolean, Now, it work well